# C programming copying an array of char to a 2d array of char

Tags: c, arrays

In this part of the project I'm trying to copy an array of char that has spaces into a 2D array of char where I want to separate each string in the 1D array before spaces and put it into the 2D array of char.

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int tracker = 0;
    char string[100];
    int b1 = 0;
    int b2 = 0;
    char bitString[100][8];


    printf("Project Zero\n");

    printf("Enter an 8-bit Binary Number!\n");

    gets(string);

    memset(&bitString[0], 0, sizeof(bitString));

    while(string[tracker] != '\0')
    {
        if(!isspace(string[tracker]))
        {
            bitString[b1][b2] = *(string+tracker);
            b2++;
            tracker++;
        }
        else
        {
            b1++;
            tracker++;
            b2=0;
        }
    }


    printf("String is: %s\n",*(bitString+0));
    printf("String is: %s\n",*(bitString+1));

return 0;
}
```

My input is this: 00001111 00001100

The result is this:
String is: 0000111100001100

String is: 00001100

I don't understand why the result for *(bitString+0) is all of the strings I entered without space.
Can someone please explain to me why this is happening and what can I do to fix it.

Comment: `for()` loops could simplify your logic

Answer (score 0):

If you change `char bitString[100][8];` to `char bitString[100][9];` it works.
I think that the C compiler automatically places the null char at the end of the row of every char array to know that the string ends there, when you write to the 7th position of bitString in one of its rows you replace the null char with a pointer to the rest of the char array `string` where the program stores the user input, so when you print it, it just keeps going until it finds the null char of `string`.
And you should include the libraries `<ctype.h> and <string.h>` to support all of the functions you use.

Comment: No this is incorrect: "C compiler automatically places the null char at the end of the row of every char array to know that the string ends there". However the `memset()` puts `0` everywhere, so, indeed, the `...[9]` would fix the problem (besides the missing controls, like size of input etc.). Note that an input of 7 bits for instance would "work" in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable b2, in the while loop, is bigger than size of `j` parameter in `char bitString[i][j];` induce to segmentation fault in the `bitString[0][8]` interaction.